# Как получить id строки DataTable по совпадению в столбце

Tags: c#, linq, select, datatable

Есть таблица с данными.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Main");
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(string)));
```

И есть данные, которые нужно добавить в таблицу, но не новые строки, а отредактировать старые.
Нужно получить `(id где Col2 == "text1")` чтобы я потом мог вставить `("textUpdate" в столбец Col3 полученного id)`
Логику можно и изменить, допустим сразу установить текст `"textUpdate" в столбец Col3 где Col2 == "text1"`

Помогите знающие.

P.S.

Вот так есть сейчас

```
id;Col1;Col2;Col3
1;str1;text1;oldText1;
2;str2;text2;oldText2;
3;str3;text3;oldText3;
4;str4;text4;oldText4;
```

Чтобы стало вот так

```
id;Col1;Col2;Col3
1;str1;text1;textUpdate;
2;str2;text2;oldText2;
3;str3;text3;oldText3;
4;str4;text4;oldText4;
```

в sql я бы сделал вот так
`select id from dt where Col2 = 'text1';`

P.P.S.
Сделал вот так вот

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Col2") == "text1")
            .Select(x => x.Field<string>("id")).First());
```

Но я практически уверен, что это можно сделать как-то проще.

И дополнительный вопрос.
Как получить не значение столбца id, а **id строки самой DataTable dt.Rows[`0`][1]**?   В случае с примером это 0 id таблицы?

P.P.P.S )
id не получилось взять, но добавить в таблицу данные сразу получилось.

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Col2") == "text1")
    .Select(r => r["Col3"] = "textUpdate").ToList();
```

Без .ToList() почему-то не добавляет.

Comment: Используйте .FirstOrDefault(), указав в нем нужные данные для поиска. Пробовали то что?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы предлагаете перебрать весь столбец `Col2` и сравнить с `"text1"`?  Это да, но как не городить циклов и найти это с помощью select linq?

Comment: Ну во первых я не вижу в ваших данных то, что вы хотите получить. Во вторых, где я хоть слова сказал про циклы?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Дополнил первый пост. Добавил данные.

Comment: в sql я бы сделал вот так  
`select id from dt where Col2 = 'text1';`

Comment: Ну ответ я вам уже дал. dt.Rows.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.НужноеСвойство == нужное значение); дальше правите то, что надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я дополнил саму тему. Если не трудно, то покажите решение пожалуйста.

Comment: Ещё раз обновил старпост. Спасибо за подсказки. Если есть решение по реальному id DataTable id строки самой DataTable dt.Rows[`0`][1] (то где 0), то буду ОЧЕНЬ ОЧЕНЬ благодарен